# Slide up whole layout when keyboard is visibile

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am working on application which will be displayed on KIOSK. And in that I have to make a screen like login screen which have Id, Password and Login button. This screen displays its content in a middle of screen. and I am displaying it like a dialog with a black window background.

Now whenever They keyboard pops up it hides the Login button which is just below the Password edittext. Which is very much not needed by client.

So I thought up to move up the whole layout only and only if the keyboard is visible else it should be centerInparent always.

I read too much on SO and I tried many solutions but did not work for me. 
I tried, adjustResize and adjustPan flag with different combination in my manifest but not having luck. I also tried it through coding but still its not working.

I do not know why it is not resizing . I think because All the edit text are already above the keyboard height and android really does not care about other widgets those are cover by keyboard if they are not edittext.

So please tell me if there is any solution. My root layout is relative layout I tried using Scrollview and different several tricks but that did not work for me.

Is there a way that can move up my layout when keyboard is shown and when keyboard hides it take back the layout to original position.

**Edit**  here is a layout

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="750dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#ff6600">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Please Login"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEnterId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblLogin"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="Enter Id"
            />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEnterPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etEnterId"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="Enter Id"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#dd33ff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout file please.

Comment: you should try wrapping your layout in scrollview and then use adjustPan/adjustResize in manifest

Comment: I did the same  @Arshad

Comment: but did not have luck

Comment: @AIK Its simple but let me post it

Comment: @AIK its updated check now